# appium ios - found text element on screen that can start with "a" or "A"

Tags: ios, appium

Im running APPIUM Automation for IOS.

I set element to click on it like this :

```
SerchField = (MobileElement)driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeCell[contains(@name,'"+ContactName+"')]"));
```

ContactName = "abcdef"

But in the mobile screen the contact name show is "Abcdef" so i get an error message that element cannot be found

how can i change the xpath so he will found the element even if the string start with "A" or "a" ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using Java.

**Using XPATH logical or**

Here `@name` shoud match any of `abcdef`, `Abcdef`.

```
ContactName = "abcdef";
String contactNameCapitalized = ContactName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + ContactName.substring(1);
String serchFieldxpath = "//XCUIElementTypeCell[(contains(@name,'"+ContactName+"')) or (contains(@name,'"+contactNameCapitalized+"'))]";

SerchField = (MobileElement)driver.findElement(By.xpath(serchFieldxpath));
```

**Using XPATH translate**

This translates all upper-case characters to lower-case. `ContactName` also should be lowercase.

```
ContactName = "abcdef";
SerchField = (MobileElement)driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeCell[contains(translate(@name,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'"+ContactName+"')]"));
```

Comment: Its working, Thanks !!

Comment: @Gil you can accept the answer, if it's helpful. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work